# mac osx el capitan. php8 for mamp 5.7

Tags: mamp, php-8

i'm running mamp 5.7 on mac osx el capitan (the last version I can use). php in this mamp version is php 7.4.
is any way to put php 8 in mamp 5.7?

many thanks

Comment: Did you find how to do this.. I have added php versions in the past, in this case php8 just cant.